# Error datatable whit ajax

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

nice to greet you.

I am trying to integrate datatable js to my plugins but it gives me a 404 error on the end point request

I am following this tutorial.

https://mogul.nz/2020/10/how-to-wordpress-jquery-datatables/

It works for me but in the console a number is added at the end of the url that I don't know where it comes from, therefore the datatable script shows an error.

this is my code

```
jQuery('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=datatables_endpoint',
      "dataSrc": "data",
      "cache":  false,
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data" : "sku" },
        { "data" : "description" },
        { "data" : "precio" },
        { "data" : "stock" },
        { "data" : "imagen" },
    ],
    pageLength: 25
  });
```

[image]

Comment: What’s the code for your endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

sorry.
I'm very sorry, I could already solve. I have my local wordpress installation in a site.test/wordpress/ subfolder and in the ajax I make the request without the subfolder.

I still have the doubt about the numbers that are added at the end of the url. :/

Comment: It's a timestamp: 1628311136453 = Saturday, 7 August 2021 04:38:56.453 UTC. I'm not sure why it's added though.